# Modify UIImage RGB CMY colors

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uicolor

First of all I'm working with OCR and I have done a huge research about it, now I got to a conclusion of what exactly I need to do, working with OCR require the UIImage to be black and white converted. Now only this specifications worked for me but I needed to do it in iOS (Swift or Objective-c) code but honestly I couldn't find a good resource which helps me to modify the image RGB CMY in the image for a percentage like Adobe Photoshop does.

[image: image1]

I really don't need to modify RBG only, its a combination which will generate a valid UIImage and works perfectly with OCR. Truly I don't have much experience in converting UIImage pixels.

Comment: Have you checked out CoreImage? This sort of thing is second nature to it.

Comment: @dfd I may have found a way to change rgb pixels but not with cym which doesn’t generate the same result expected.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but - *"My CMYK Levels filter applies individual multipliers to the cyan, magenta, yellow and black channels of an RGB image converted to CMYK. "*. A few links: (1) The blog http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2016/04/new-custom-core-image-filters.html (2) The Swift 2 code https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Filterpedia/blob/master/Filterpedia/customFilters/CMYKRegistrationMismatch.swift

Comment: Simon has an iBook out written in Swift 2, now available free as either iBook or PDF: http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2016/03/core-image-for-swift-v12-released.html Some of it is CIKernel code, which is a subset of GLSL code. Hope it helps you out.

Comment: @dfd appreciated I’ll check them out :)